# Orientdb: Create new Graph database

Tags: java, orientdb, tinkerpop

I'm trying to create a new instance of OrientGraph database, as follows:

```
OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("local:C:/temp/graph/db");
graph.create(); //BUT no create method!!
```

anyhow, while sticking with the manual and do it with ODatabaseDocumentTx like:

```
db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("plocal:c:/orientdb/db");
db.create();
....
db.shutdown();
```

then I want to get a session like:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:c:/orientdb/db", "admin", "admin");
OrientGraphNoTx g = factory.getNoTx();
try
{

}
finally
{
    g.shutdown();
}
```

I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static method     com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.checkForGraphSchema(Lcom/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/document/ODatabaseDocumentTx;)
```

**How Can I create a new graph database???**

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should not use the "local" engine anymore, it is deprecated (your first example). Secondly, the way an OrientGraph must be created is clearly documented, see http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Factory.html

The complete example which should work:

```
@Test
public void testNoTx() {
    // start with a non existing database
    final OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(
        "plocal:" + DB_DIR, "admin", "admin");
    assertFalse(factory.exists());        
    try {
        OrientGraphNoTx g = factory.getNoTx();
        // database is auto created
        assertFalse(g.isClosed());
        assertFalse(g.isRequireTransaction());
    } finally {
        // this also closes the OrientGraph instances created by the factory
        // Note that OrientGraphFactory does not implement Closeable
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

Finally, your reported error indicates a set of inconsistent jar files. You should:

- use Java 6+ (for version < 2.x) or 7+ (for version >= 2.x, this is **not** documented)
- use the jars mentioned here: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html **from OrientDB** (OrientDB uses a *modified* tinkerpop implementation). Best is to use maven :)

Needed dependencies:

```
- com.orientechnologies:orientdb-graphdb:jar:2.0-M2:compile
  +- com.orientechnologies:orientdb-core:jar:2.0-M2:compile
  |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.0.1:compile
  |  +- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-  lru:jar:1.4:compile
  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.0.0:compile
  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.0.0:compile
  \- com.tinkerpop.blueprints:blueprints-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.3:compile
     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
     +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.6.0:compile
     \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
        +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
        +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
        +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
        |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
        \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
```

### UPDATE:

For a complete example, see https://github.com/rmuller/graphdb-playground (under 'orientdb-embedded-graph')

Comment: maybe I'm not lucky with orientdb, let me give it a final try... I did exactly as your code (without Asserts) and I get:
'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: supportsThreadIsolatedTransactions'

Compiled on Java 1.7 with the following Maven dependencies:
orient-commons 2.0-M1
orientdb-core 2.0-M2
blueprints-core 2.5.0
orientdb-graphdb 2.0-M2
  any idea!

Comment: Okay, that makes it clear. Your dependencies are not consistent, see my updates answer. I assume that when OrientDB is final, they will provide an `orientdb-graph-all.jar` or something like that. For now, if not using maven you have to collect these file yourself. But, it really should work, without problems!

Answer (score 0):

After a wild struggling with V2 I went back to V.1.7.9 and everything works.

Maven Dependency:
    
        com.orientechnologies
        orientdb-graphdb
        1.7.9

it seems that there are some unsolved issues with V.2.x I will do another PoC within a month or so.

Comment: See my updated answer with a link to a complete "ready to run" example. You should get it running within 5 minutes :)